# List all Group linked in ACL for specific User

Tags: groups

How do I list group linked for a specific user in CiviCRM

Example: I have three user group in Civi - Admin, user and staff

I have linked only one group (staff contact) for staff user with ACL

Now If I login has staff user he can only see (staff contact) group

I need SQL or a civiCRM function which can return me the group based on Contact_ID

[image]
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to list the group linked with contact based on ACL

$group = CRM_ACL_API::group(2,$request_contactID);

The above API group function returns the group ID for the requested contact ID

Thanks